# Nginx reverse proxy, failed to access server using server name

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I’m adding NGINX to my MERN app as a reverse proxy. I need Nginx to forward all requests to the node server that runs on port 4000. I add the following server block to the default nginx.conf, in which I add the server_name and the proxy_pass.

```
    server{
      listen 80;
      server_name douban;
      location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For
$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      }
  }
```

$ sudo nginx -t   shows me the config is correct

then I run $ sudo nginx -s stop && sudo nginx to start Nginx, and $ npm start to start my backend server

The problem is, I cannot access my server using the server_name (127.0.0.1:douban). Is my reverse proxy working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NGINX you `server_name` is not a port that you define to access the app from

`server_name` is a the domain, IP, etc... that you would forward to a custom port

for example, I want to bind the domain api.example.com to port 4000 and example.com to port 3000 and anything else to port 5000

you'll create 2 server blocks

the 1st will have `server_name` with api.example.com and the `proxy_pass` will be http://localhost:4000

the second will have `server_name` with example.com and the `proxy_pass` will be http://localhost:3000

the last one will have `server_name` with _ and the `proxy_pass` will be http://localhost:5000

hope that my answer is clear

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access Nginx with the server_name.
Please check how server_name works
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

You can access your Nginx with YOUR_NGINX_IP:80 (listen port) only.